# Xcode Breakpoint not being triggered even though method is called

Tags: swift, xcode, breakpoints

My breakpoints seem to be playing up.  I was finding that some breakpoints were triggering and others weren't.  Here is one example:

I've tried creating a new iOS App project (interface: Storyboard, Life Cycle: UIKit App Delegate).  The only code change I have made is this:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        print("traitCollectionDidChange -- called --")
}
```

I then have a breakpoint on the print line.  The project builds and runs and if I change the Environment Overrides to change the Text/Dynamic Type size, the above print statement is logged but the breakpoint does not trigger.

I've checked a number of different settings as suggested here and from other sources but I can't work out how to fix this.  I've checked the schemes, the preferences, deleted the DerivedData file, even re-installed xCode...  Also tried re-installing command line developer tools.

I've spent hours trying to work this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have logged a defect with Apple in the meantime.  It seems that when using the Accessibility Inspector to make Font Size changes, then `traitCollectionDidChange` is called (as it is with Environment Overrides) but the difference is that with the Accessibility Inspector, the breakpoint ***is*** triggered.  If you go back to Environment Overrides, then it 'breaks' Accessibility Inspector, and then `traitCollectionDidChange` is no longer called and the corresponding breakpoint is also not triggered.  A rebuild resets this issue.

Comment: Are other breakpoints being hit? If not - are you running in debug or release mode?

Comment: Yes. Other breakpoints get hit. I just noticed that some aren’t. Running in debug mode.  Other breakpoints are working but some aren't as above.  I haven't been able to discern any difference between the ones that are and ones that aren't.

Comment: Maybe it helps to export the breakpoints to JSON and check if there is something strange inside. To export, use `breakpoint write -f ~/breakpoints.json` in the debug console.

Comment: Then try a brute fore. I'll post an answer, because the comment field is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Try a brute force attack:

1. Create a global function

```
func forceBreakpoint() {
    print ("breakepoint hit")
}
```

2. call that function

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    print("traitCollectionDidChange -- called --")
    forceBreakpoint()
}
```

3. create a symbolic breakpoint for `forceBreakpoint`

Run the app and hope the breakpoint hits now.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually tried that.  Breakpoint isn't triggered although the print statement is called.  A simulator device rotation does trigger the breakpoint though (and the print statement).

Comment: and what is the output of `br list` for that breakpoint? You should get something like `language = swift, locations = 1, resolved = 1, hit count =` and then a `0` if it has not been hit, or a `1` if it has.

Comment: So that's interesting...  The hit count is showing the correct count with `br list` even though Xcode never 'paused' at that breakpoint....